# Proper way to extend class/method functionality - using NLog as example

Tags: c#, .net, oop, nlog, extend

I'm using the NLog .NET logging library here as an example; my question isn't specific to NLog.

Typical NLog logging looks like this:

```
private static Logger log = LogManager.GetLogger("logger_name");
log.Info("Some log message");
```

I want to add functionality to the Info() method.  Perhaps I want some timestamp added to the log message.

The way I've accomplished is absolutely horrendous and just stinks of code smell.

I created a helper class which holds a `Logger` instance, implements it's own (but named the same) `GetLogger()` and `Info()` methods (ugh, just terrible), and then includes some custom functionality in `Info()`.

```
public static class NLogLogManagerHelper // Can't derive from LogManager because it's sealed
{
    public static string _loggerName;
    public static NLog.Logger _log;

    public static NLog.Logger GetLogger(string loggerName)
    {
        _loggerName = loggerName;
        _log = LogManager.GetLogger(loggerName);
        return _log;
    }

    public static void Info(string message)
    {
        var eventInfo = new LogEventInfo(LogLevel.Info, _loggerName, message);
        // Add some custom functionality
        eventInfo.Properties["mytimestamp"] = Time.ConvertUtcToEst(DateTime.UtcNow);
        _log.Log(eventInfo);
    }
}
```

I'm not even sure that taking the approach of making a helper and wrapping a Logger is the right approach.

This "works" but is stinky as heck.  One big stink is that it's NLog's `Logger` class that has the `Info()` methods, so I could create a `MyLogger` which inherits from `Logger`, but then I can't implement `Info()` because it's not overridable.  Another stink is that since I've duplicated the Info() method I don't have access to any of it's overloads.  I'd like to know the proper way to approach this problem, whether it's an OO approach, or a design pattern, or whatever.

Comment: It depends on the exact behavior you want to modify and possibly on other factors as well like how are instances being referenced. There is no one right answer to this, you could read up on some of the [behavioral design patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavioral_pattern) to give you some more insight.

Comment: Did you try to use [Layout renders](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Layout-renderers) or create a custom render?

Comment: @GeorgeAlexandria No - I'm just using NLog as an example of something I want to extend.  It's really a design question not an NLog question.

Comment: I think this question belongs better on CodeReview, not to SO as you don't really have a problem.

Answer (score 3):

There is at least one definite code smell, and that is that calling your `GetLogger()` method with different `loggerName` values will overwrite *both* `static string _loggerName` and `static NLog.Logger _log` (which should also both be private, by the way), meaning that in such a case you can't subsquently call your `Info()` method in a reliable way.

You might better just use an extension method on an `NLog.Logger` instance that you created the regular way. Extension methods are a great way of making it look like you are extending a class, even if in reality you can't, and at the same time never having to mention the static class (just add a `using`-line for its namespace).

```
public static class NLogHelper
{
    public static void StampedInfo(this NLog.Logger logger, string message)
    {
        var eventInfo = new LogEventInfo(LogLevel.Info, logger.Name, message);
        eventInfo.Properties["mytimestamp"] = Time.ConvertUtcToEst(DateTime.UtcNow);
        logger.Log(eventInfo);
    }
}

// usage:
//   var log = LogManager.GetLogger(loggerName);
//   log.StampedInfo("message");
```

Comment: Briliant, but you have to change it to extending the `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` because that is getting injected everywhere, same method applies.